# Check when folder was last synchronized with rsync

Tags: 12.04, cron, rsync

I'm using a cron job to backup a folder to another computer. I'm not sure whether or not it succeeded and `/var/log/rsync.log` is only showing errors, all of which occured before the scheduled backup. There is a record of the backup job being run in `/var/log/syslog`.

Is there a way of checking when the folder was last synced or is another way of telling whether the sync succeeded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a note to the log after the sync finished. add it to the cronjob:

```
0 12 * * * rsync ... /source /dest && echo 'finished on' $(date) >> /var/log/rsync.log
```